# How to pass JSON array and object in Rest API

Tags: c#, json, rest, api

I want to passs below JSON in Rest API

```
{"fulfillment":{"order_id":67584463,"tracking_number":"555555","tracking_url":"test.com","fulfillment_line_items":[{"order_line_item_id":186994328,"quantity":1}]}}
```

**i will try below method but it not good**

```
var client = new RestClient("XXXXX");    
var request = new RestRequest(Method.POST);    
request.AddHeader("postman-token", "asds373jkhsstpolsd");    
request.AddHeader("cache-control", "no-cache");    
request.AddHeader("content-type", "application/json");    
request.AddParameter("application/json", "{\"fulfillment\":  {\"order_id\":67584463,\"tracking_number\":\"555555\",\"tracking_url\":\"test.com\",\"fulfillment_line_items\":[{\"order_line_item_id\":186994328,\"quantity\":1}]}}", ParameterType.RequestBody);    
IRestResponse response = client.Execute(request);
```

Comment: What error message are you getting ? And why would you pass a `postman-token`

Comment: i want need how to pass above mentioned JSON data  in Rest API , plz don't consider postman token and other request header just focus on how to pass JSON in rest api

Comment: i want to pass mentioned JSON data in rest API **{"fulfillment":{"order_id":67584463,"tracking_number":"555555","tracking_url":"test.com","fulfillment_line_items":[{"order_line_item_id":186994328,"quantity":1}]}}**

Answer (score 0):

Just use the `AddBody` method to pass the body.

```
var client = new RestClient("XXXXX");    
var request = new RestRequest(Method.POST);   
requst.AddBody = (jsonString); //Your json string goes here
```